# Can we call methods with parameters in Struts2 fieldexpression?

Tags: validation, struts2, expression

I've configured my sturts2 application to use the validation xml for my actions. I also  have fieldexpression working.

Would it be possible to call a method from my action in the expression.
eg:

```
<field name="myField">
  <field-validator type="fieldexpression">
    <param name="expression"><![CDATA[
      @com.test.MyClass@isCaptchaOk(keyString, userResponce)
    ]]></param>
    <message>My credit limit should be MORE than my girlfriend's</message>
  </field-validator>
</field>
```

Here is my actual test code, the simple fieldexpression works, but function call one does not (see the tbox1). 
I'm not sure if the @class@method path is ok or not, but is not working
coz, I've added log in the functions but nothing comes up, so i presume the validator can't reach the functions.

Also, Is this possible, ie is it allowed or am i being too ambitious.

Thanks

PS I've corrected the message, I'm not trading my girlfriend ;-)
************ validation.xml

```
<!DOCTYPE validators PUBLIC  
            "-//OpenSymphony Group//XWork Validator 1.0.2//EN"  
            "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/xwork-validator-1.0.2.dtd">
<validators>
    <field name="tbox1">
        <field-validator type="fieldexpression">
            <param name="expression"><![CDATA[@uk.co.nhbc.userRegistration.action.Test2Action@getString()]]></param>
            <message>function call message here</message>
        </field-validator>
    <field-validator type="fieldexpression">
        <param name="expression"><![CDATA[@uk.co.nhbc.userRegistration.action.Test2Action@isCaptchaOk(tbox1, user.username)]]></param>
        <message>function call message here</message>
    </field-validator>
    </field>
    <field name="tbox2">
        <field-validator type="stringlength">
            <param name="maxLength">5</param>
            <message>length messssage here</message>
        </field-validator>
    </field>
    <field name="user.username">
        <field-validator type="fieldexpression">
            <param name="expression"><![CDATA[(!(tbox2 == "aa" && user.username.equals("")))]]></param>
            <message>tbox2 eq aa and username is empty messssage2 here</message>
        </field-validator>

    </field>

</validators>
```

*********** java class

```
package uk.co.nhbc.userRegistration.action;

import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;

import uk.co.nhbc.common.action.BaseAction;
import uk.co.nhbc.userRegistration.model.Users;

public class Test2Action extends BaseAction {
    private String tbox1;
    private String tbox2;
    private Users user;
    private static final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(Test2Action.class);

    public String execute() {
        return SUCCESS;
    }

    public String getTbox2() {
        return tbox2;
    }

    public void setTbox2(String tbox2) {
        this.tbox2 = tbox2;
    }

    public String getTbox1() {
        return tbox1;
    }

    public void setTbox1(String tbox1) {
        this.tbox1 = tbox1;
    }

    public Users getUser() {
        log.debug("get user called");
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(Users user) {
        log.debug("set user called");
        this.user = user;
    }

    public boolean isCaptchaOk(String challenge, String response) {
        //dummy test function
        log.debug("captcha function called");
        if (response.equals("true"))
            return true;
        return false;

    }
    public String getString (){
        log.debug("getString function called");
        return "hello";

    }

}
```

*************and jsp page

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="sj" uri="/struts-jquery-tags"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<s:form name="formtest" action="Test2Action">
<s:actionerror/>
<s:fielderror></s:fielderror>
<s:textfield name="tbox1" label="box1"></s:textfield>
<s:textfield name="tbox2" label="box1"></s:textfield>
<s:textfield name="user.username" label="boxuser"></s:textfield>
<s:submit></s:submit>
</s:form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you try it? (And I'm pretty sure you mean "more than my girlfriend's [is]", unless you trade people.)

Comment: hy Dave, yes I tried it, I've add my actual (crude) test code files above

Comment: no, it did not, see my code and please point our any errors

Comment: What are `keyString` and `userResponce`?

Comment: (I'm not sure if static method invocation will work or not anyways, mind you. Do you have static methods turned on in your config?)

Comment: the parameters for the function isCaptchaok, and would be input items on the jsp page being passed to the params. I think the problem is that i cannot see any entry in the log file, so the function is not being called

Comment: I mean where do they come from.

Comment: I guess my question wud be is it possible to call a method (static or not) from fieldexpression. if Yes then how, under what conditions and my methods or class is not static.

Comment: they come from the jsp page (input items on the page), just please see my new edit to the question i've added all the files (different to previous example)

Comment: You can certainly call methods on the values; it's just OGNL. You *should* be able to call static methods if static method invocation is enabled. What I'm not sure about is if you have complete/any access to the request's value stack.

Comment: hy dave, based on your comments on static and value stack. I changed the field expression to  <field name="tbox1">
  <field-validator type="fieldexpression">
   <param name="expression"><![CDATA[isCaptchaOk(tbox1, user.username)]]></param>
   <message>function call message here</message></field-validator>
 </field> and now it is working

Comment: thanks dave I'll add it to the main page

Comment: Awesome :) I'm not even sure how to convert the conversation into an answer so it can be accepted ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See my updated working validator file. for field tbox1 in the fieldexpression I'm referring to the method directly as it is my action, which would be on the VS. 
tbox1 and user.username are  items on the jsp page (and also exist in the action)

I tried to experiment with a static method, but that didn't work, (no time to investigate now).
Hope this helps
and thanks dave for the input.

*******updated validation xml

```
<!DOCTYPE validators PUBLIC  
            "-//OpenSymphony Group//XWork Validator 1.0.2//EN"  
            "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/xwork-validator-1.0.2.dtd">
<validators>
    <field name="tbox1">
        <field-validator type="fieldexpression">
            <param name="expression"><![CDATA[isCaptchaOk(tbox1, user.username)]]></param>
            <message>function call message here</message>
        </field-validator>
    </field>
    <field name="tbox2">
        <field-validator type="fieldexpression">
            <param name="expression"><![CDATA[(@uk.co.nhbc.userRegistration.action.Test2Action@isFuncOk(tbox2))]]></param>
            <message>func okk function call message here</message>
        </field-validator>
    </field>
    <field name="user.username">
        <field-validator type="fieldexpression">
            <param name="expression"><![CDATA[(!(tbox2 == "aa" && user.username.equals("")))]]></param>
            <message>tbox2 eq aa and username is empty messssage2 here</message>
        </field-validator>

    </field>

</validators>
```

*******updated java class

```
package uk.co.nhbc.userRegistration.action;

import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;

import uk.co.nhbc.common.action.BaseAction;
import uk.co.nhbc.userRegistration.model.Users;

public class Test2Action extends BaseAction {
    private String tbox1;
    private String tbox2;
    private Users user;
    private static final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(Test2Action.class);

    public String execute() {
        return SUCCESS;
    }

    public String getTbox2() {
        return tbox2;
    }

    public void setTbox2(String tbox2) {
        this.tbox2 = tbox2;
    }

    public String getTbox1() {
        return tbox1;
    }

    public void setTbox1(String tbox1) {
        this.tbox1 = tbox1;
    }

    public Users getUser() {
        log.debug("get user called");
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(Users user) {
        log.debug("set user called");
        this.user = user;
    }

    public boolean isCaptchaOk(String challenge, String response) {
        //dummy test function
        log.debug("captcha function called");
        log.debug("captcha function called"+challenge+response);
        if (response.equals("true"))
            return true;
        return false;

    }
    public String getString (){
        log.debug("getString function called");
        return "hello";

    }

    public static boolean isFuncOk (String response){
        log.debug("isFuncOk function called"+response);
        if (response.equals("true"))
            return true;
        return false;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to calling a static method in expression, which must be OGNL, you should enable struts.ognl.allowStaticMethodAccess by adding below constant to struts.xml file:

> < constant name="struts.ognl.allowStaticMethodAccess" value="true"/>