# Struts2 xml-validation calling a method

Tags: java, xml, validation, struts2, struts

Is it possible for an xxx-validation.xml to call  a method? since my plan is that I would check a certain a value that it have received from the form and pass it as a parameter in a method (checks if the username exist in the db)

or ActionSupport class will invoke the validation.xml and then do a certain method

Comment: Why not simple put that logic inside `validate` method inside action?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As i answered [in a question from two days ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13927830/combining-validate-method-and-xml-validation-in-struts2) (!!), it is:

```
<validators>
    <field name="username">
        <field-validator type="fieldexpression">
            <param name="expression">
                <![CDATA[
                    isUserAlreadyInDatabase(username)
                ]]>
            </param>
            <message>function call message here</message>
        </field-validator>
    </field>
</validators>
```

Please consider to vote  :)

Comment: Oops, I didn't saw your answer from my previous question. Sorry low latency internet connection here. but wait, where would I register or create that method? is there a class I should use?

Comment: your Action (or an Action extended by your Action, let's say BaseAction, if the method to call is common...)

Comment: is this considered as bad practice?

Comment: I used this to check data from session, I've never did it to query a database, i wrote that would be a bad practice but I may be wrong... i'll edit to put some doubt on it :)